# Is there another logic that handles the session in Chrome?

Tags: spring, google-chrome, session, google-chrome-devtools, spring-session

I use Spring, log in using Session.
Login processing works well in other browsers (IE, Safari.....), Even on mobile chrome!
Only Desktop Chrome says there is no session value.

When the Interceptor checks for logins,
Only in Desktop Chrome, it says `admin==null` in the code below.

`AdminM admin = (AdminM)session.getAttribute("LoginedAdmin");`

Is there another logic that handles the session in Chrome?

Plz, Help me~

Comment: Are you using the spring-session project? i.e do you include a dependency like `spring-session-data-redis`?

Comment: No, I'm not.. but, thanks :)

Comment: This was Chrome same site Issue..